# Clicking JPanel with inner components

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouse-listeners

I have a main `JPanel` class (not exact code):

```
class Panel extends JPanel {
   public void initGUI() {
    setLayout(...);
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel boxPanel = new JPanel(...);
    tabbedPane.addTab("test", boxPanel);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Label")
    boxPanel.add(label);
    add(tabbedPane);
  }
}
```

I want to be able to click anywhere on the Panel or its inner components and return the Panel.

```
public class PanelMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { 
      Panel panel = (Panel)e.getSource();
      //do other stuff
   }
}
```

And for each Panel I'm adding this mouse listener.

But it only works around the edges of the Panel, any inner components are ignored. I need it to be able to click anywhere in that Panel.

I need to maintain that anywhere I click it will return the Panel object (as in the mouse listener).

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Do the components held by the JPanels have either MouseListeners directly added to them by you, or indirectly added by Java (such as with JButtons, JTextComponents, etc...)?

Comment: If you target to open a `JpopupMenu` you can use `JComponent.setComponentPopupMenu` and it should work on the panel and its descendants.

Comment: The only listener I'm applying is attached to the Panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Container#getComponents()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29) for this case. For example consider the code snippet given below (look for `addListeners(Container)` method):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
class SPanel extends JPanel
{
    public void init()
    {
        this.add(new JButton("Button"));
        this.add(new JLabel("Click"));
        JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        pan.add(new JButton("PanButton"));
        pan.add(new JTextField(29));
        add(pan);
        addListeners(this);
    }
    public void addListeners(Container comp)
    {
        Component[] components = comp.getComponents();
        for (Component component : components)
        {
            if (component instanceof Container)
            {
                Component[] child = ((Container)component).getComponents();
                if (child != null && child.length > 0)
                {
                    addListeners((Container)component);
                }
            }
            component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)
                {
                    System.out.println(evt.getSource().getClass());
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                SPanel sp = new SPanel();
                sp.init();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
                frame.getContentPane().add(sp);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the issue. You are just adding the mouselistener to all the child components. But if I click on the inner component it doesn't return the Panel object it just returns the source object clicked on. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: if there would be a way to get the Panel from the child object clicked on, then it would be okay solution. Guess I will just have to create separate objects for each item inside and pass the Panel instance.

Comment: What you mean by inner components?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question. Your demo code only shows a single panel, so why do you care what parent panel is clicked on? The better your explanation of the requirement the better the solution we can provide.

Anyway, check out [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/). This will allow you to listen for a mousePressed event (which is a better then listening for a mouseClicked).

Next you need to create a custom panel (MyCustomPanel) that you use for the top level panel.

Now, whenever a mousePressed is generated you can get the source of the event and then use:

```
MyCustomPanel panel = SwingUtilties.getAncestorOfClass(MyCustomPanel.class, (Component)event.getSource());
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue.

Initially I was going to open a popup menu once I had the mouse listener in place.

But now I added JComponent.setComponentPopupMenu as Polum suggested, not to the Panel but to the tabbedPane.

Then I added a listener to the popup menu, got the source object via event in popupMenuWillBecomeVisible method, then the component via source.getInvoker(), then get the parent of the invoker component and check if its an instance of PairBox.